# JavaScript - instantiate multiple objects of the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I have been attempting to organise my JavaScript/jQuery somewhat better, but am having trouble with objects.

Please take a look at this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4tz6ynns/)

The fundamental pieces are as follows:

```
(function($){

    $.toast = function(params) {
         return new toast(params)
    }

    var toast = (function(params){
        var params = params;
         var show = function()  {
            // getToast() returns jQuery DOM object
            getToast().show();
        }

        // Public API
        return {
            show : show
        }

    });

}(jQuery));

$(document).ready(function(){
    var toast1 = $.toast(params);
    var toast2 = $.toast(params);
    toast1.show();
    toast2.show();
});
```

The trouble lies where I am calling a function on the object(s) created.
Within the `$(document).ready()` function, I instantiate 2 objects, which I then call show() on.

The show() method simply changes the display property.

Only one of the toasts shows, however.

I've looked into different ways of instantiating the objects to no avail.

I've also moved around the "new" keyword, also to no avail.

I started my journey to cleaner IS with object literals, but I had trouble binding events to the correct object. Done weird stuff was happening where the bound function was being applied to all objects.

I like the way I instantiate the toasts, so I'd like for the code within the `$(document).ready()` to stay the same, if possible.

Any/all help is appreciated as I probably need a jolt in the right direction.

Cheers.

Comment: Can you post the code for getToast()?

Comment: Take a look at the fiddle, it's all in there :) (it's just that I'm on my mobile and it's very hard to type code)

Comment: Oh ok. Missed the fiddle. Sorry. Looking now.

Comment: That `return new toast` wrapper is completely useless. Your `toast` function returns an object, so there's no reason to call it with `new`. Just move all your code directly inside of `$.toast`.

Comment: try to add `var ` before the function definition of `getToast`.

Comment: `new` isn't meaningless. It might not be of any use in this implementation, but `return new {}` and `return {}`are not equivalent.

Comment: Yes , problem is with getToast code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your defining `getToast` as a global function since you are missing the `var` statement in front of it. So it should be:

```
var getToast = function(){
};
```

Comment: Ha nice. I was staring at that fiddle for too long.

Comment: *sigh...I just new I'd make myself look like an idiot!!! I think sometimes you need to leave a couple of hours before you can go back and see the obvious. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In `getToast`, you have this piece:

```
        getToast = function(){

            if ( $toast !== undefined ) return $toast;

            ...
        }
```

This returns an existing $toast if there is one, and when the first toast is created, such an object exists and is subsequently returned. This appears to be the problem, from what I gather.

Answer (score 0):

Change function definition to return the unique toast not same toast of 
`getToast().show();`

```js
(function($){

    $.toast = function(params) {
         return new toast(params)
    }

    var toast = (function(params){
        var params = params;
         var show = function()  {
            // getToast() returns jQuery DOM object
           //getToast().show();
             alert(params)
        }

        // Public API
        return {
            show : show
        }

    });

}(jQuery));


    var toast1 = $.toast('params1');
    var toast2 = $.toast('params2');
    toast1.show();
    toast2.show();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```